# Programmatically adding context-scoped onCompletion() to Camel Context

Tags: java, apache-camel

Is there a way to add an *onCompletion* context-scoped 'handler' to the Camel context? The [Camel onCompletion documentation](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html) shows how to do it with the Spring XML DSL and I have not been able to find a way to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
// define a global on completion that is invoked when the exchange is complete
onCompletion().to("log:global").to("mock:sync");
```

Comment: I tried this without luck:

camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
   @Override
   public void configure() throws Exception {
      onCompletion().to("log:com.company.project.insights.log.output?level=INFO");
   }
});

No messages are ever shown in my log. Obviously, I add other routes with separate camelContext#addRoutes calls that use separate RouteBuilder implementations.

Comment: make sure you are adding onCompletion() in the same RouteBuilder that you want to add this behavior to...

Comment: Because of my current design, I'm adding multiple routes to the Camel Context using separate RouteBuilder implementations and CamelContext#addRoutes calls. When I tried adding the onCompletion() in one of these RouteBuilder#configure() methods, it was added to the route that was being built in there.

Comment: in theory, you should be able to use includeRoutes(RouteBuilder) to get them all in the same RouteBuilder to reuse the onCompletion() then...

Answer (score 1):

As onComplete can only be `RouteBuilder` scope. To create a truly global onComplete processor

```
// Initialize an instance of the definition
OnCompletionDefinition globalOnComplete = new OnCompletionDefinition();
globalOnComplete.to("log:onComplete");
```

In your `RouteBuilder` implementation before you define any routes add the instance above to the definition

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    // Add onCompletion instance for all routes within this RouteBuilder
    this.getRouteCollection()
            .getOnCompletions()
             .add(globalOnComplete);


    // Route definition
    from("direct:input").to("log:output");        
}
```